# Numbering on the paper does not follow from the abstract page

Tags: titles, page-numbering, abstract

My page numbers are not following a proper order. Right now what I have is the Abstract page numbered 1, but the Introduction page is also numbered 1. I want the numbers to follow from the Abstract page, that is, 1, 2, 3, and so on. The numbering starts in the Abstract and ends in the very last page of the paper going all the way through.

This is what I have on my preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %the depth of section numbering 0 means no
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

**EDIT:**

My abstract is in the title page and the intro:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\title{\textbf{Title }\\
{\small \textbf{    }}}


\author{\\John Doe\footnote{Department of XXX, University of XXX, City, State Postal Code, Country. E-mail: \url{johndoe@uni.edu}.}\\ \small{Department of XXX, University of XXX}}
\date{ \small {\today}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
 Blah blah
\end{abstract}
\noindent \textit{blah:} XX; XX\\
\noindent \textit{Keywords:} X; X; X
\end{titlepage}

%Need to look into Nash Bargaining with interest R costs taken into account. will change x_underline (cutoff)
%\doublespacing
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{page}{2} %solves the problem
\section{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}
```

Comment: I put \setcounter{page}{2} before \section{Introduction}
and it seems to  have solved the problem

Comment: While I answered your question, there are a number of other things wrong with your minimal example: `\small` is a declaration, not a macro that takes an argument; it seems like you thing `\small{<stuff>}` will put `<stuff>` in a small font. While it will, the correct use is `{\small <stuff>}`. The "department" text doesn't form part of the `\author` definition, as you have a unpaired closing `}`. There's also no way to break a line using ``\\`` within that line.

Comment: I have made an edit. I am  just following a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the reason behind what you're seeing: Since you're not using `article` under the `compatibility` class option, the `titlepage` environment is defined in the following way:

```
\newenvironment{titlepage}
  {%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse\newpage
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \setcounter{page}\@ne
  }%
  {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
   \if@twoside\else
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
   \fi
  }
```

Note how the page number is set to 1 (`\setcounter{page}\@ne`) at the end of the `\begin{titlepage}` definition as well as at the end of the `\end{titlepage}` definition *if* you're not in `twoside` mode. You're not in `twoside` mode either, so the page number is reset to 1 as you notice.

The easiest solution is to set it to 2 manually using `\setcounter{page}{2}` or `\addtocounter{page}{1}` after `\end{titlepage}`.

Comment: Thanks! Already have done that but good to know the actual reason.